# how to get output from lpsolve in R

Tags: r, desktop

How to get output from `lpsolve` in R. All i get is the optimized value of the objective function. I need to know the value of the decision variables.

**Output that I get :**

`returnValue(output) Success: the objective function is 1189245444`

**Help needed :** I need to know the exact values of the decision variables behind the objective function.

Comment: Could you show the input as well?

Answer (score 0):

with some googling the solution is that if the lp() output is ascribed to, say, output. The value of the decision variables can be gauged from output$solution